# Organize single column in pandas to make multiple columns and dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have created a DataFrame in Pandas from some webscraping with BeautifulSoup but every time I try to organize it, it goes and does something I don't want it to do.

Essentially I have gotten it to pull the data that I want but now I want to create two seperate dataframes from it.

The first dataframe looks like this ('|' is the separator on the title) :

```
City             | ave 1 Sqft | ave 1 BR rent| ave 2 BR Sqft | ave 2 BR rent| ave 3 BR Sqft | Ave 3 BR Re 
Saratoga Springs   868         $1199          1149             $1389         1426             $1599
```

The second dataframe looks like this:

```
City | Per capita income | Median Household Income | Total Pop | Ave Age | Ave Rent | Monthly rent change
SS     $37221             $75991                    653282      30 Yrs Old  $1199     8.34%
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import pandas as pd

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
})

url = 'https://www.apartments.com/apartments/saratoga-springs-ut/1-bedrooms/'

requests.get(url, headers=headers)

function_usage = []

for item in description:
    item = item.text
    function_usage.append(item)

data = pd.DataFrame({'function_usage':function_usage})
data
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have searched the internet up and down and can't find exactly what I am looking for so any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I missed something? The response `r` is not used to extract data.

Comment: Yeah, obviously you can tell that I am new to Python. I have removed the r to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is the value of the `description` variable and therefore of `function_usage`?